# Batch File to rename txt file

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch file that renames a text file with the file content. for example flie1.txt containing the word alpha becomes alpha.txt. I just some tips of what commands to use to create this batch file.

Comment: Is this unix, Windows, mac...?

Comment: I tried using the rename command

Answer (score 1):

This only uses the first line or word in the file:

```
set/p var=<file.txt     ---Setting a variable to the content inside the file.
ren file.txt %var%.txt  ---Renaming the file to eh assigned variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

windows `move`.  unix `mv`

*Example*

Windows:

```
move my_original_file_name.txt my_new_file_name.txt
```

Unix:

```
mv  my_original_file_name.txt my_new_file_name.txt
```

*Your specific task* in Windows:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set your_file_location=%userprofile%
set your_file_name=!your_file_location!\file1.txt

for "eol=; tokens=1 delims=" %%n in ('type "!your_file_name!"') do (
  set new_file_name=%%n
)
move "!your_file_name!" "!your_file_location!\!new_file_name!.txt"
```